# Firebase cloud function not updating record

Tags: reactjs, list, firebase, favorites

imagine this scenario:

You have a list with lets say 100 items, a user favorites 12 items from the list.

The user now wants these 12 items displayed in a new list with the up to date data (if data changes from the original list/node)

What would be the best way to accomplish this without having to denormalize all of the data for each item?

is there a way to orderByChild().equalTo(**multiple items**)

(the **multiple items** being the favorited items)

Currently, I am successfully displaying the favorites in a new list but I am pushing all the data to the users node with the favorites, problem is when i change data, their data from favorites wont change.

*note - these changes are made manually in the db and cannot be changed by the user (meta data that can potentially change)*

---

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to achieve this now with cloud functions. I am trying to update the item but I can't seem to get it working.

Here is my code:

```
exports.itemUpdate = functions.database
  .ref('/items/{itemId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const before = change.before.val();  // DataSnapshot after the change
  const after = change.after.val();  // DataSnapshot after the change

  console.log(after);

  if (before.effects === after.effects) {
    console.log('effects didnt change')
    return null;
  }
   const ref = admin.database().ref('users')
   .orderByChild('likedItems')
   .equalTo(before.title);

   return ref.update(after);
});
```

I'm not to sure what I am doing wrong here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do multiple items in the orderByChild, denormalising in NoSQL is fine its just about keeping it in sync like you mention. I would recommend using a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions) which will help you to keep things in sync.

Another option is to use Firestore instead of the Realtime Database as it has better querying capabilities where you could store a users id in the document and using an array contains filter you could get all the users posts.

The below is the start of a Cloud function for a realtime database trigger for an update of an item.

```
exports.itemUpdate = functions.database.ref('/items/{itemId}')
    .onUpdate((snap, context) => {
        // Query your users node for matching items and update them
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, this is just what I need. I have tried to accomplish this with cloud functions I'm having issues... I updated my answer with code for this, mind taking a look?

Comment: There is no `.set()` parameter on `.equalTo()` you need to get the results from the query back and then loop through that to update them all. I would suggest getting Visual Studio Code as it will be able to give you the IntelliSense to help you write your code as it would of told you `.set()` doesnt exist on `.equalTo()`

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for this. I have been spending way to much time trying to resolve this... This is my first go at cloud functions - I am still having issues trying to get a simple console log from my forEach. There seems to be not much documentation for this. I updated my question again, I am getting the first console.log but not the one inside the forEach... Is there something I am doing wrong? Cheers.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio code you will get all the Intellisense to troubleshoot this. You are using snapshot twice so thats not a good practice to shadow variables. and you cant do a forEach on the second snapshot as thats not your data. if you do `snapshot.val()` then you can access the `forEach()`.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I am going to have to give visual studio a shot, I'm currently using Atom which displays errors for everything except for cloud functions... I updated my question, I have no clue why this isn't executing. I'm not to sure where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hey Jack, is there a specific plugin you use for the firebase intellisense?

Comment: No, just works for me. Visual Studio Code not Visual Studio though.

Comment: Okay great - I got the intellisense working. Thank you. I am still struggling with this function/query. This question was getting out of hand so I posted a new one with where I am currently at with things. I'd appreciate if you had a look at it to guide me in the right direction. Cheers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399903/firebase-cloud-function-wont-return-anything-from-foreach